# How to implement coffeescript to work after a 401 ajaxerror?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, devise, coffeescript

I'm building a reddit/angellist clone. I want to be able to upvote and downvote without the page reloading. I've the ajax setup via the votescontroller:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to request.referer }
    format.js
end
```

and then in the upvote.js.erb:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#vote-sum").html("<%= pluralize(@votable.votes.sum(:value), 'vote') %>");
});
```

So far all good. When clicking on up the sum instantly changes.

This all happens when a user is logged in. When a user is not logged in, and you press the up link, I get a `401`, because I use Devise I have `before_action :authenticate_user!` in my votes controller. I get this as output on my local server:

```
Started POST "/items/11/upvote" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-02 17:52:06 +0100
Processing by VotesController#upvote as JS
  Parameters: {"item_id"=>"11"}
  Item Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "items"."created_at" DESC LIMIT $2  [["id", 11], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

I want to automatically send the user towards the sign in page. So I googled for answers and found one, with a great answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10460074/6430382

I have to insert these lines of code:

```
$ ->
  $("a").bind "ajax:error", (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) ->
    if jqXHR.status == 401 # thrownError is 'Unauthorized'
      window.location.replace('/users/sign_in') // or with .replace(this)
```

However when I add these lines it does not work. I changed the `$("a")` to `$(document)`. Or even changed this to vanilla JS:

```
$(function() {
  return $(document).bind("ajax:error", function(event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
    if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
      return window.location.replace('/users/sign_in');
    }
  });
});
```

sidenote: a normal console.log('!') and alert('!') works fine in the `application.js` or the `votes.coffee` code.

I expect the code to redirect a user towards the devise sign in page.

Other similar resources I've looked at:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34434921/6430382

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9903564/6430382

[Devise authenticate_user! breaks when making remote: true requests to a non-devise controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41050915/devise-authenticate-user-breaks-when-making-remote-true-requests-to-a-non-devi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a small break I came back and started to research some other questions that I didn't see before.

Solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45168313/6430382

Create a method & implement above (before) the `before_action :authenticate_user!`

```
def check_user
  return if user_signed_in?
  redirect_to new_user_session_path, error: 'You must log on to view this part of the site'
end
```

Add to controller

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :check_user

  ...
end
```